# maven: run cucumber test after the deploy

Tags: maven, spring-boot, cucumber

I am working on The integration of Cucumber with spring boot application to test my Rest webservices.

When I run the application and then I run `mvn test` in the project, it works fine for me. But this is not what I need. Actually I want it to me more automated.
I want to run the test using **only** the command `mvn clean install`. but this command run directly the test without running the application so the test always fails *"connection refused"*, this is normal because the application is not running.

My question is there a solution to run the app before running cucumber tests when I use the command `mvn clean install`

For that purpose I created a simple spring boot application using spring initializr (I added only web).
After that I added cucumber dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

So my pom.xml looks like this:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>cucumber</groupId>
<artifactId>hellocucumber</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>hellocucumber</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

then I created a controller to test it with cucumber:

```
@RestController
public class VersionController {
    @GetMapping(path="/version")
    public String getVersion() {
        return "1.0";
    }
 }
```

for cucumber config I created this class

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/features/", plugin = "pretty")
public class HelloCucumberCucumberRunnerTest {

}
```

Also I created my feature file

```
 Feature: the version can be retrieved
      Scenario: client makes call to GET /version
        When the client calls /version
        Then the client receives status code of 200
        And the client receives server version "1.0"
```

And steps definition class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class VersionSteps{


    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Value("${app.url}")
    String url;

    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity;

    @When("^the client calls /version$")
    public void the_client_calls_version() throws Throwable {
        url += "/version";
        this.responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
    }

    @Then("^the client receives status code of (\\d+)$")
    public void the_client_receives_status_code_of(int serverStatus) throws Throwable {
       assertEquals(responseEntity.getStatusCode().value(), serverStatus);
    }

    @Then("^the client receives server version \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void the_client_receives_server_version(String version) throws Throwable {
        assertEquals(responseEntity.getBody(), version);
    }
```